# Vakil FOAG Exercise12.3 C (part c)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let X be a closed subscheme of dimension r in $\mathbf{P}^n_A$, where A is a Noetherian ring. Part C of Exercise 12.3.C of Ravi Vakil's notes(August 29,22 edition) requires one to show that; we may choose r+1 hypersurfaces such that the intersection of these hypersurfaces avoids X.

I am not able to show this. We have to use Krull's principal ideal theorem but I am not able to see how to use this. Can someone help me with this?